# Angular 5 - FileUpload not working

Tags: node.js, angular, express, file-upload

Edit: Fixed. I had to add this to my response:

```
.subscribe(data =>{
  console.log('data is here: ', data);
});
```

I have read through whole bunch of articles on this one, but cannot get it to working.

Environment: Angular 5, NodeJS backend with Express. Using Express-FileUpload to upload the file.

I tried my API with this simple HTML:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <form ref='uploadForm' 
      id='uploadForm' 
      action='http://192.168.1.20:8275/api/upload' 
      method='post' 
      encType="multipart/form-data">
        <input type="file" name="sampleFile" />
        <input type='submit' value='Upload!' />
    </form>     
  </body>
</html>
```

Figured that my API is working fine, the API End point receives the request from HTML just fine. Now, this is what I am trying to do Angular:

```
let body = new FormData();
  body.append("file", file, 'thefilename');
  let options: RequestOptions = new RequestOptions();
  options.headers = new Headers();
let response: Observable<Response> = this.http.post('http://192.168.1.20:8275/api/upload', body, options); //code just breaks here and exists silently

response.map(json =>{
  console.log('gotcha')
}),err =>{
  console.log('error: ', err);
};
```

Angular code doesn't work. After the POST call, it breaks and exits silently. Nothing in console, no error. And I am unable to figure out why? I read through articles, and found we don't have to supply a content type to make it work. I tried that too but no luck. What can be the issue?

Comment: Did you try using the stable HttpClient https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpClient ? Here is a working example https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-5-file-upload

Comment: Do you get any errors in the console?

Comment: No errors... it just exists... http I am using from is this: node_modules/@angular/http/http.d.ts

Comment: @Oo-_-oO Http is deprecated https://angular.io/api/http/Http . Would be better to move on to the one I've written to you in the first comment

Comment: Sure @StefanosChrs, I will make sure to use the newer version. I didn't use subscribe with this older http, so it was not submitting the request. I had to add this: .subscribe(data =>{
  console.log('data is here: ', data);
});